# How to run nestjs app using docker compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, nestjs

Trying to run my nestjs app with mariadb using docker compose

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /user/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm ci --omit=dev

RUN npm run build

USER node

CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

and dockercompose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file:
    - .env
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    restart: always
    container_name: MARIADB
    networks:
      - mariadb
    env_file:
      - docker.env      
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

networks:
  mariadb:
    driver: bridge
```

i am getting the following error

```
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | > ecommerce-backend@0.0.1 start /usr/src/app
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | > node dist/main
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:934
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |   throw err;
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |   ^
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/dist/main'
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:15)
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:27)
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |   requireStack: []
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | }
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | ERR! 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | code
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |  ELIFECYCLE
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm ERR! errno 1
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm ERR! ecommerce-backend@0.0.1 start: `node dist/main`
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | ERR!
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |  Exit status 1
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |  ERR!
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |  
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm ERR!
ecommerce-backend-app-1  |  Failed at the ecommerce-backend@0.0.1 start script.
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | 
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
ecommerce-backend-app-1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-10T08_03_32_813Z-debug.log
ecommerce-backend-app-1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: your dockerfile is working fine, I think you need to provide some more details about the project

Comment: The error message includes a path `/usr/src/app` (without an `e`) that doesn't seem to appear in your Docker setup at all; can you double-check that the file contents you've posted are correct?  The `app` container has a `volumes:` block that could cause this error, if the paths matched, and I'd delete that.  You're not there yet but the `networks:` setup will also cause problems and I'd delete the two `networks:` blocks as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze i added those tring to mitigate the error (following a blog posts)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nest changed the default build path from dist to build.

I had to change the start:prod script to `"node build/src/main"`